# utimes() and utimensat() syscalls hangs for 90 sec

Tags: linux, system-calls, xfs

CentOS 7.6, `xfs` filesystem:

We observe hanging backup and compile jobs because `utimes()` and `utimensat()` syscalls hang on random files for 90 sec. xfs mount options are

```
rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota
```

The part of the filesystem where we observe these delays are exported by kernel-nfs.
What are the reasons for the 90 sec delays and how to prevent this?